# Choosing the pivot for a QuickSort

Tags: java, pivot, quicksort

I have found the code. But i don't understand how it is working.
As i know pivot - its middle element of array. 
 But here pivot is `int pivot = quickSortArray[p]` where, int i = p, so p = 0 and 0 it is not middle of array, can an explain me this ?

```
 public int partition(int p, int q) {
    int i = p;
    int j = q + 1;
    // Get the pivot element from the middle of the list
    int pivot = quickSortArray[p];
    // Divide into two lists
    do {
        // If the current value from the left list is smaller then the pivot
        // element then get the next element from the left list
        do {
            i++;// As we not get we can increase i
        } while (quickSortArray[i] < pivot && i<q);
        // If the current value from the right list is larger then the pivot
        // element then get the next element from the right list
        do {
            j--;// As we not get we can increase j
        } while (quickSortArray[j] > pivot);
        // If we have found a values in the left list which is larger then
        // the pivot element and if we have found a value in the right list
        // which is smaller then the pivot element then we exchange the
        // values.
        if (i < j) {
            swap(i, j);
        }

    } while (i < j);
    // swap the pivot element and j th element
    swap(p, j);
    quickSortComparisons++;
    return j;

}

private void swap(int p, int j) {
    // exchange the elements
    int temp = quickSortArray[p];
    quickSortArray[p] = quickSortArray[j];
    quickSortArray[j] = temp;
    quickSortSwaps++;
}

public void quicksort() {
    // Recursion
    quicksort(0, quickSortCounter - 1);
}

public void quicksort(int p, int q) {
    int j;
    if (p < q) {
        // Divide into two lists
        j = partition(p, q);
        // Recursion
        quicksort(p, j - 1);
        quicksort(j + 1, q);
    }
    quickSortComparisons++;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot doesn't have to be the middle element. It just has to be a random element. The code fixes the pivot to be always the first element probably to make the code easier. It's not optimal because if you have an array sorted descendingly, it'll take `O(n^2)` rather than `O(n log n)`. The optimal would be to pick an element randomly.